# Data Doesn't Come in Requests Response

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am new to python, data scraping, and automation. I am trying to scrape the website given in `URL`. When I open the `URL` link in browser all the data is shown however the response of the `requests.get()` method doesn't give that data.

It would be really helpful if anyone can tell me what's going wrong.

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = "https://fees.uspto.gov/MaintenanceFees/fees/details?applicationNumber=12814074&patentNumber=7871455"
html = requests.get(URL)
time.sleep(4)
pno = response.findAll('div',{"class":"left maintenanceFeeDetails"})
print(pno)
```

The data I want to scrape is under payment window status (just paste the url from `URL` in your browser)

Comment: The URL returns a 302. You have to follow to the URL given in the `Location` header.

Comment: What is `response` supposed to be? Also the sleep is pointless, requests is not going to be rendering any dynamic content,  any  302s are handled by requests so you do get the source. The real issue is what you are after is dynamically created

Comment: Really many Thanks. That helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment the data you want is dynamically generated so it is simply not in the source you get returned, requests handles redirects for you automatically for get requests so that could also never really be an issue:

You can get the info you want can be done by mimicking an ajax request  using a simple get request to `https://fees.uspto.gov/mntfee-services/v1/maintenancefee/details` with the same params:

```
params = {"patentNumber": "7871455",
          "applicationNumber": "12814074"}

api = "https://fees.uspto.gov/mntfee-services/v1/maintenancefee/details"

data = requests.get(api, params=params).json()
```

Which gives you all the info in a json format.

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: params = {"patentNumber": "7871455",
   ...:           "applicationNumber": "12814074"}

In [3]: api = "https://fees.uspto.gov/mntfee-services/v1/maintenancefee/details" 
In [4]: data = requests.get(api, params=params).json()

In [5]: data["infoMessageText"]
Out[5]: [u'No maintenance fees are due at this time. 7.5 year window opens on 01/18/2018.']

In [6]: info = data["model"][0]
In [7]: info.keys()
Out[7]: 
[u'patentStatus',
 u'feeStatus',
 u'geoRegionCode',
 u'category',
 u'patentNumber',
 u'subCategory',
 u'streetLineTwo',
 u'applicationNumber',
 u'applicationStatusDate',
 u'abandonmentDate',
 u'nationalStageIndicator',
 u'window',
 u'version',
 u'postalCode',
 u'nameLineOne',
 u'issueDate',
 u'maintenanceFeePhases',
 u'streetLineOne',
 u'filingDate',
 u'countryName',
 u'phone',
 u'correspondenceAddressIndicator',
 u'entityTypeName',
 u'nameLineTwo',
 u'applicationStatus',
 u'entityTypeCd',
 u'cityName',
 u'feeCodes',
 u'patentTitle',
 u'customerNumber',
 u'windowStatus']

In [8]: info["patentStatus"]
Out[8]: u'ACTIVE'

In [9]: info["feeStatus"]
Out[9]: u'Not Due'
In [10]: info
Out[10]: 
{u'abandonmentDate': -62135578800000,
 u'applicationNumber': u'12814074',
 u'applicationStatus': 150,
 u'applicationStatusDate': 1293512400000,
 u'category': u'UTL',
 u'cityName': u'LOS ANGELES',
 u'correspondenceAddressIndicator': True,
 u'countryName': u'UNITED STATES',
 u'customerNumber': u'33417',
 u'entityTypeCd': u'S',
 u'entityTypeName': u'SMALL',
 u'feeCodes': [],
 u'feeStatus': u'Not Due',
 u'filingDate': 1276228800000,
 u'geoRegionCode': u'CA',
 u'issueDate': 1295326800000,
 u'maintenanceFeePhases': [{u'closeDate': 1421730000000,
   u'expiredDate': 1421816400000,
   u'feeStatus': u'Paid',
   u'openDate': 1390021200000,
   u'statementStatus': u'Statement',
   u'surchargeDate': 1405742400000,
   u'transactionId': u'020314INTMTFEE00001905503725',
   u'version': 0,
   u'window': u'3.5',
   u'windowStatus': u'Closed'},
  {u'closeDate': 1547787600000,
   u'expiredDate': 1547874000000,
   u'feeStatus': u'Not Due',
   u'openDate': 1516251600000,
   u'statementStatus': None,
   u'surchargeDate': 1531972800000,
   u'transactionId': None,
   u'version': 0,
   u'window': u'7.5',
   u'windowStatus': u'Not Open'},
  {u'closeDate': 1674018000000,
   u'expiredDate': 1674104400000,
   u'feeStatus': u'Not Due',
   u'openDate': 1642482000000,
   u'statementStatus': None,
   u'surchargeDate': 1658203200000,
   u'transactionId': None,
   u'version': 0,
   u'window': u'11.5',
   u'windowStatus': u'Not Open'}],
 u'nameLineOne': u'LEWIS, BRISBOIS, BISGAARD & SMITH LLP',
 u'nameLineTwo': u'JON E HOKANSON',
 u'nationalStageIndicator': u'N',
 u'patentNumber': u'7871455',
 u'patentStatus': u'ACTIVE',
 u'patentTitle': u'JET ENGINE PROTECTION SYSTEM',
 u'phone': u'2132501800',
 u'postalCode': u'90071',
 u'streetLineOne': u'633 WEST 5TH STREET',
 u'streetLineTwo': u'SUITE 4000',
 u'subCategory': None,
 u'version': 0,
 u'window': u'7.5',
 u'windowStatus': u'Not Open'}
```

You can pull whatever info you want from the models dicts.

Comment: +1 An API when available is always more reliable and faster than scraping with BeautifulSoup or Selenium.

Comment: Thank you Very much, it really helped

Comment: I will remember to use the Api next time

Answer (score 0):

I tried with `allow_redirects=True` and `headers` param with  User Agent, still got noting:

```
URL = "https://fees.uspto.gov/MaintenanceFees/fees/details?applicationNumber=12814074&patentNumber=7871455"
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"}
response = requests.get(URL, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
print(response.history)
divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='left maintenanceFeeDetails')
print(divs)
```

It follows redirects, but I get nothing

```
[<Response [302]>, <Response [302]>, <Response [302]>]
[]
```

### The data seems to be dynamically loaded, so I used Selenium

With Selenium I get the results

```
from __future__ import print_function

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://fees.uspto.gov/MaintenanceFees/fees/details?applicationNumber=12814074&patentNumber=7871455")

div = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.left.maintenanceFeeDetails')
maintenance = div
print(maintenance.text)

driver.close()
```

Results (the headers of the table from which you can extract data)

```
PATENT #
APPLICATION #
FILING DATE
ISSUE DATE
Payment Window Status
WINDOW
STATUS
FEES
Patent Holder Information
Customer #
Entity Status
Phone Number
Address
```

Comment: Thank you very much